# Is there a plugin allowing me to get version subcomponents in a maven build?

Tags: maven, plugins, version

In my maven build, I want to access to majorVersion and minorVersion of the project currently built. I tried writing [gmaven-plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Executing+Groovy+Code) groovy script, but it failed; I also tried extracting it using [properties-maven-plugin](http://evgeny-goldin.com/wiki/Properties-maven-plugin), but I only get a string view of the groovy script I write. So, how can I get the version as multiple elements instead of a simple String ?

Comment: For which purpose do you need those information?

Comment: @khmarbaise creating continous integration domains, one for each version of my app, on the same machine - and as a consequence with adminport computed from application version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one called [`build-helper-maven-plugin`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/parse-version-mojo.html). It will let you parse the version of your pom and place a new variable called `parsedVersion` to use inside your pom.

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <id>parse-version</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>parse-version</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${parsedVersion.majorVersion}</finalName>
</build>
```